# error message saying onclick javascript function does not exist

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, button

I am building a simple web application and it includes altering other variables when a form is submitted. I have successfully attached onclick functions to other buttons but for some reason this one won't work. I have tried multiple ways to write the programs( details later) but nothing seems to be working.

Here is the HTML

```
<form name="customChange" id="customChange">
  <label for="custom">
    Enter a number to change BPM :
    <input
      id="custom"
      type="number"
      placeholder="Enter positive or negative number"
      name="customChangeNumber"
    />
  </label>
</form>
<button id="customBtn" onclick="customChange()">Change</button>
```

Here is the javascript

```
function customChange() {
  let change = document.getElementById("custom").value;

  calculateCustomBPM(change);

  let secPerBeat = 60 / BPM;
  heart.style.animationDuration = secPerBeat + "s";
  document.getElementById("BPM").innerHTML = BPM;
}
```

And here is the error message displayed by the console.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTg2j.png)

```
error message: Uncaught TypeError: customChange is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

I have tried adding an event listener, placing the button inside the form, and much other stuff but I cannot figure out the issue.

Also, I can't seem to prevent the page reload when the button is within the form, so any help with that is welcome too.

Comment: Could you add some details about how you are including the script on the page? A link to a CodePen or CodeSandbox that illustrates the problem would be very helpful :)

Comment: it is strange to me, but it is related to the name of the form, if it is changed the script works properly.

Comment: Not sure why your function name isn't being recognized, but the default behavior of a button within a form is to submit the form. And the default behavior for submitting a form is to send the form to the current URL. Your click handler needs to have a parameter like `function customChange(event)` and then call `event.preventDefault()` to stop this behavior.

Comment: @Mario  yess i changed the form name and it worked, thank youu

Answer (score 4):

Just change the function name. it's causing the issue because form name is also the same.

I've tried your question and I was getting same error, then I've changed the name and it's working.

Either change the function name or update form tag's name field.

Comment: Yess i figured it out soon after, changed the form name, and it worked. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This could be why:

> ## Function shares a name with a pre-existing property
>
> Sometimes when making a class, you may have a property and a function with the same name. Upon calling the function, the compiler thinks that the function ceases to exist.

Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you would like to help and contribute then I recommend you visit [help]. We appreciate your help, but we really do expect higher quality answers than just quoting from the documentation.